# JSON - Php/SQL iPhone APP Questions/Help

Tags: iphone, cocoa, json, uilabel

Hey group, first time posting here

I am somewhat new to the JSON/PHP/mySQL world, but been around iPhone designing for the past few years, though this topic of conversation is a while new area I am entering.

I have done JSON iPhone examples that allow me to create a UITableView and display the JSON data into the TableViewCells (CustomCells) and displays the data (NSDictionary)into UILabels

The problem I am having now, is that I want an APP that displays this information from the JSON into just a couple of UILabel's on a regular UIViewController and not a UITableView

any help would greatly be appreciated,

the example I used and learned for JSON and UITABLE was from http://tempered.mobi/%20 
I used that example from my app, but incorporated a few other things like CUSTOM cells

however now when the USER selects the specific CELL I want it to load specific data from another JSON file, and cannot get it to load in a UILabel or UITextView in a UIViewController

HELP :-)

Comment: show some code, its a long enough question already though...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I completely understand your query, when the user clicks on a table cell you want the app to do a request for data in JSON format and display it in labels on a view? correct?

If so, then I'd modify the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. Use the index to determine which JSON request to fire, load the results into object/array/dictionary and then set the labels text from this data source.

Apologizes if I mis-understood your question.

Comment: hey its ok, sorry for my beginners explanation, that is what I want, however I have the didSelectRowatIndexPath setup properly, it loads my specific XIB for that cetrtain tablecell, it also loads the JSON data and prints it in a NSLOG, however when i try to print to a UILabel it receives a (null) give me a couple of moment's I shall post my code below...

Comment: Hey again, I've a question from looking at your console output: As far as I'm aware JSON is returned as a string, shouldn't there be quotes around Mississauga and Brampton?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my coding to it, this is the XIB that is loaded once the TABLEViewCell is selected, i apologize in advanced for the formatting, I dont know why it is not coming out properly as I am simply copying and pasting from Xcode

.h File, all I added was

```
IBOutlet UILabel *homeTeam;
IBOutlet UITextView *homeTeam2;
IBOutlet UILabel *awayTeam;
NSArray *rows;
```

}
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *rows;

(added note: I obviously hooked up the UILabels and UIText View to my labels and text view in that specific XIB) and have tested  using the homeTeam.text = @""; (in the Implementation file)to make sure they are functioning properly

.m file

## import "CJSONDeserializer.h"

## import "JSON.h"

@synthesize homeTeam, awayTeam, awayTeam2;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourserver.com/yourdata.json"]; // Modify this to match your url.

  NSString *jsonreturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url]; // Pulls the URL
  //NSLog(jsonreturn); 
  // Look at the console and you can see what the restults are

  NSData *jsonData = [jsonreturn dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
  NSError *error = nil;

  // In "real" code you should surround this with try and catch
  NSDictionary * dict = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error];
  if (dict)
  {
      rows = [dict objectForKey:@"users"];
      [rows retain];

  }
  NSLog(@"Array: %@",rows);   //making NOTE this NSLOG does print my JSON Data grabbed from the SQL Database

  awayTeam2.text =[dict objectForKey:@"awayteam"];
  awayTeam.text = [dict objectForKey:@"awayteam"];

  [jsonreturn release];

CONSOLE: as you can see it grabs my JSON data just fine....
Array: (
        {
        awayicon = "Brampton.png";
        awayteam = Mississauga;
        homeicon = "Mississauga.jpg";
        hometeam = Brampton;
        hscfinal = 10;
        id = 1;
    }
)